# Getting the following on Windows 11 via Github desktop /usr/bin/env: ‘bash’: No such file or directory

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I am very new GitHub and I am getting the following on Github Desktop on Windows 11:
/usr/bin/env: ‘bash’: No such file or directory

I have even tried uninstalling and re-installing. Please any help would be appreciated

[image]